# Not performing all code in For Loop

Tags: java, android

I am trying to cycle through all parts of a `HashMap` using a for loop. The problem however is, that inside the body of the for loop, the code is not being fully performed. That is , it is happening only to a certain point and is then stopping.My code is:

```
public static void printCombination(String arr[], int n, int r)
{
    // A temporary array to store all combination one by one
    Log.e("ERROR","ATLEAST I'M INSIDE");
    String data[]=new String[r];
    for(int no = 0;no<arr.length;no++){
        boolean decider = true;
        if (latest.cart_names.size()>0) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry : latest.cart_names.entrySet()) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "ATLEAST I'M INSIDE 1");
                String arrayElement = arr[no];
                Map<String, Integer> outerMapValue = entry.getValue();
                Log.e("ERROR", "ATLEAST I'M INSIDE 2");
                if (outerMapValue.containsKey(arrayElement)) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "ATLEAST I'M INSIDE 3");
                    if (outerMapValue.get(arrayElement) != null) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "ATLEAST I'M INSIDE 4");
                        if (outerMapValue.get(arrayElement) > 0) {
                            return;
                        }else{
                            Log.e("ERROR", "ATLEAST I'M INSIDE 5");
                            decider = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.e("ERROR",Boolean.toString(decider));
            Log.e("ERROR",Integer.toString(finalmap.size()));
            if (finalmap.size()==0) {
                if (decider) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "ATLEAST I'M INSIDE 8");
                for (int rt = 0; rt < latest.cart_names.size(); rt++) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "ATLEAST I'M INSIDE 6");
                    finalmap.add(rt,arr[no]);
                }
            }
        }else{
            if (decider) {
                int sum1 = 0;
                int sum2 = 0;
                for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry : latest.cart_names.entrySet()) {
                    sum1 += latest.cart_names.get(entry.getKey()).get(finalmap);
                    sum2 += latest.cart_names.get(entry.getKey()).get(arr[no]);
                }
                Log.e("ERROR",Integer.toString(sum1));
                Log.e("ERROR",Integer.toString(sum2));
                if (sum2>sum1){
                    for (int rt = 0; rt < latest.cart_names.size(); rt++) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "ATLEAST I'M INSIDE 7");
                        finalmap.add(arr[no]);
                    }
                }
            }

            }
    }}
```

It is not logging lines:

```
Log.e("ERROR",Boolean.toString(decider));
Log.e("ERROR",Integer.toString(finalmap.size()));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition is met and the returning/exiting the method...

```
if (outerMapValue.get(arrayElement) > 0) {
    return;
```

## Edit:

as [@petey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794088/petey) and [@Andrew L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5647260/andrew-l) commented (Thanks for the suggestions (: )

you should consider to take a look to the java best practices and how to use [branching control statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

> The continue and break statement can be used to skips the current iteration of a for,
>   while , or do-while loop.

Comment: You should mention the use of the continue keyword just for guidance. If he wants to exit the loop and perform the rest, recommend break.

Comment: You should offer the correct keyword of `break` and explain its usages for stopping a for loop differently than using `return`

Comment: I will add your suggestions @AndrewL, thanks for the comments though....

Comment: Thanks @ΦXoce 웃 Пepeúpa, although I will not be using either or break as  I still want to carry out the rest in the for loop. The only reason I am using if (outerMapValue.get(arrayElement) > 0) {}else something and not if (outerMapValue.get(arrayElement) ==0) { is because  it gives nullpoinerexception.

Comment: Thanks @ΦXoce 웃 Пepeúpa, although I will not be using either or break as

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it's not logging the lines you list because of the `return` statement inside the loop. If you want the loop to terminate at that point and still log the lines, you should use `break` instead.